# How to access the last element in an array ?

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

In my hive table, the `session` field is a string in format like:

`ip-sessionID-userID` or `area-sessionID-userID`

There's 3 or 4 fields separated by "`-`", but userID is always the last one.

i wanna select userID, but how to access the last field? In python, there's something like:

`arr[-1]`

but in hive, how to achieve this? The following SQL seems not correct.

`select split(session,"\-")[-1] as user from my_table;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

```
reverse(split(reverse(session), '-')[0])
```

Although this might be a bit more expensive than the regex solution ;)

Comment: Love this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because Non-constant expressions for array indexes not supported in hive.

There will be some other ways to solve your problem:

1. use `regexp_extract`, such as :

   select regexp_extract(session, '(\-[^\-]+)', 1) as user from my_table;
2. use custom hive function : example and document could be found in [hive document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins)

Comment: This regex solution did not work in case array only have one element.

Comment: try  `regexp_extract(session, '([^\-]+)$', 1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would be faster than the solution from @arno_v, because it only reverse the view array elements, instead of the whole string, and only reverse once:

```
reverse(split(session, '-'))[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

One more method without `reverse`, using array `size()-1`. This method is more efficient because it does not produce intermediate reversed string, it works only with array.

```
select array[size(array)-1] as userID
from
( select split(session,'-') array from your_table ) s;
```